# pip didn't install package from requirements.txt but did from command

Tags: python, pip

I've two files related to requirements. I was getting this error, when calling:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file:///tmp/packages
```

**Error:**

```
Looking in links: file:///tmp/packages
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref==3.2.3 in d:\virtual_envs\scolarte\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements-dev.txt (line 1)) (3.2.3)
Collecting boto3==1.12.0 (from -r requirements-dev.txt (line 2))
  Url 'file:///tmp/packages' is ignored: it is neither a file nor a directory.
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3==1.12.0 (from -r requirements-dev.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for boto3==1.12.0 (from -r requirements-dev.txt (line 2))
```

But the package installed when calling:

```
pip install boto3==1.12.0
```

**why?**

a) requirements.txt:

```
-r requirements-dev.txt
gunicorn
psycopg2
```

b) requirements-dev.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.3
boto3==1.12.0
botocore==1.14.16
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch==20181111
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==3.0.3
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
django-import-export==2.0.1
django-sendgrid-v5==0.8.1
django-storages==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
docutils==0.15.2
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
future==0.18.2
jdcal==1.4.1
jmespath==0.9.4
MarkupPy==1.14
numpy==1.18.1
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.3
pandas==0.25.3
Pillow==7.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-decouple==3.3
python-http-client==3.2.4
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3
s3transfer==0.3.3
sendgrid==6.1.1
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
static3==0.7.0
tablib==0.14.0
urllib3==1.25.8
xlrd==1.2.0
xlwt==1.3.0
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are using

```
pip install boto3==1.12.0
```

You are installing from [PyPI (The Python Package Index)](https://pypi.org/). Whereas by using the `--no-index` option in

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file:///tmp/packages
```

you are explicitly telling `pip` not to look for it in the PyPI.

Form the [PyPI Documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-index)

> **--no-index**
>
> Ignore package index (only looking at --find-links URLs instead).
>
> **-f, --find-links** `<url>`
>
> If a url or path to an html file, then parse for links to archives. If a local path or file:// url that’s a
>   directory, then look for archives in the directory listing.

Also on [how pip finds packages](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#finding-packages) (emphasis mine)

> pip looks for packages in a number of places: **on PyPI (if not disabled
>   via --no-index)**, *in the local filesystem, and in any additional
>   repositories specified via --find-links or --index-url.* There is no
>   ordering in the locations that are searched. Rather they are all
>   checked, and the “best” match for the requirements (in terms of
>   version number - see PEP 440 for details) is selected.

Comment: Firts I tried: `pip install boto3==1.12.0` but got the same error.

Comment: @OmarGonzales It might be due to the fact that you might have installed  `botocore==1.14.16` first.  https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/setup.py has a dependency of `botocore>=1.15.0,<1.16.0`. It still does not explain why it worked for you the second time. Unless it got upgraded (or uninstalled) somehow.